# Implementation of Levenshtein distance for mysql/fuzzy search?

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm, search, levenshtein-distance

I would like to be able to search a table as follows for smith as get everything that it within 1 variance.

Data:

```
O'Brien
Smithe
Dolan
Smuth
Wong
Smoth
Gunther
Smiht
```

I have looked into using Levenshtein distance does anyone know how to implement this with it?

Answer (score 12):

In order to efficiently search using levenshtein distance, you need an efficient, specialised index, such as a [bk-tree](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees). Unfortunately, no database system I know of, including MySQL, implements bk-tree indexes. This is further complicated if you're looking for full-text search, instead of just a single term per row. Off-hand, I can't think of any way that you could do full-text indexing in a manner that allows for searching based on levenshtein distance.

Answer (score 8):

There is a mysql UDF implementation of Levenshtein Distance function

https://github.com/jmcejuela/Levenshtein-MySQL-UDF

It is implemented in C and has better performance than the "MySQL Levenshtein distance query" mentioned by schnaader

Comment: Is this fast enough for real time use, when searching say 200,000 records?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by real-time. On a test box with two Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 0 @ 2.70GHz CPUs and 64G memory, the following queries finished in 0.30 seconds.  'select min(levenshtein(country, 'GC')) from countries;'. The countries table has a column country of 2 chars. And the table contains 1M rows +

Comment: @Hongzheng its only on 2 letters try benchmarking with higher numbers

Comment: @talsibony why not trying yourself?

Answer (score 6):

The function given for levenshtein <= 1 above is not right -- it gives incorrect results for e.g., "bed" and "bid".

I modified the "MySQL Levenshtein distance query" given above, in the first answer, to accept a "limit" that will speed it up a little.  Basically, if you only care about Levenshtein <= 1, set the limit to "2" and the function will return the exact levenshtein distance if it is 0 or 1; or a 2 if the exact levenshtein distance is 2 or greater.

This mod makes it 15% to 50% faster -- the longer your search word, the bigger the advantage (because the algorithm can bail earlier.)  For instance, on a search against 200,000 words to find all matches within distance 1 of the word "giggle," the original takes 3 min 47 sec on my laptop, versus 1:39 for the "limit" version.  Of course, these are both too slow for any real-time use.

Code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein_limit_n( s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255), n INT) 
  RETURNS INT 
  DETERMINISTIC 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost, c_min INT; 
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR; 
    -- max strlen=255 
    DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256); 
    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0, c_min = 0; 
    IF s1 = s2 THEN 
      RETURN 0; 
    ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN 
      RETURN s2_len; 
    ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN 
      RETURN s1_len; 
    ELSE 
      WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
        SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1; 
      END WHILE; 
      WHILE i <= s1_len and c_min < n DO -- if actual levenshtein dist >= limit, don't bother computing it
        SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, c_min = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1; 
        WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
          SET c = c + 1; 
          IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN  
            SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1; 
          END IF; 
          SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost; 
          IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF; 
            SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1; 
            IF c > c_temp THEN  
              SET c = c_temp;  
            END IF; 
            SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1;
            IF c < c_min THEN
              SET c_min = c;
            END IF; 
        END WHILE; 
        SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1; 
      END WHILE; 
    END IF;
    IF i <= s1_len THEN -- we didn't finish, limit exceeded    
      SET c = c_min; -- actual distance is >= c_min (i.e., the smallest value in the last computed row of the matrix) 
    END IF;
    RETURN c;
  END$$
```

Answer (score 5):

An implementation for the damerau-levenshtein distance can be found here:
[Damerau-Levenshtein algorithm: Levenshtein with transpositions](http://blog.lolyco.com/sean/2008/08/27/damerau-levenshtein-algorithm-levenshtein-with-transpositions/)
The improvement over pure Levenshtein distance is that the swapping of characters is considered. I found it in the comments of schnaader's link, thanks!

Comment: unfortunately this result in it being 10% slower. I have however implemented the string length, he proposes using string at max or smaller, I have implemented a compare on only string +/- 1 length.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to know if the levenshtein-distance is at most 1, you can use the following MySQL function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `lv_leq_1` (
`s1` VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
`s2` VARCHAR( 255 )
) RETURNS TINYINT( 1 ) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i INT;
    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), i = 1;
    IF s1 = s2 THEN
        RETURN TRUE;
    ELSEIF ABS(s1_len - s2_len) > 1 THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
    ELSE
        WHILE SUBSTRING(s1,s1_len - i,1) = SUBSTRING(s2,s2_len - i,1) DO
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
        RETURN SUBSTRING(s1,1,s1_len-i) = SUBSTRING(s2,1,s2_len-i) OR SUBSTRING(s1,1,s1_len-i) = SUBSTRING(s2,1,s2_len-i+1) OR SUBSTRING(s1,1,s1_len-i+1) = SUBSTRING(s2,1,s2_len-i);
    END IF;
END
```

This is basically a single step in the recursive description of the levenshtein distance.
The function returns 1, if the distance is at most 1, else it returns 0.

Since this function does not completely compute the levenshtein-distance, it is much faster.

You can also modify this function such that it returns `true` if the levenshtein-distance is at most 2 or 3, by calling it self recursively. If MySQL does not support recursive calls, you can copy slightly modified versions of this function two times and call them instead. But you should not use the recursive function to calculate the exact levenshtein-distance.

Comment: Do you mean at least 1?

Comment: @MarkFisher No. it returns 1 (true) if the distance is lower or equal to 1.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Chella's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909885/how-to-add-levenshtein-function-in-mysql) and Ryan Ginstrom's [article](http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2007/12/01/fuzzy-substring-matching-with-levenshtein-distance-in-python/), a fuzzy search could be implemented as so:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION fuzzy_substring( s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255) )
    RETURNS INT
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR;
    -- max strlen=255
    DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256);
    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0;
    IF s1 = s2 THEN
        RETURN 0;
    ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN
        RETURN s2_len;
    ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN
        RETURN s1_len;
    ELSE
        WHILE j <= s2_len DO
            SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(0))), j = j + 1;
        END WHILE;
        WHILE i <= s1_len DO
            SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1;
            WHILE j <= s2_len DO
                SET c = c + 1;
                IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN
                    SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1;
                END IF;
                SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost;
                IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
                    SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1;
                IF c > c_temp THEN
                    SET c = c_temp;
                END IF;
                SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1;
            END WHILE;
            SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END IF;
    SET j = 1;
    WHILE j <= s2_len DO
        SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10);
        IF c > c_temp THEN
            SET c = c_temp;
        END IF;
        SET j = j + 1;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN c;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 3):

I am setting up a search based on Levenshtein or Damerau-Levenshtein (probably the latter) for multiple searches over an indexed text, based on a paper by  by Gonzalo Navarro and Ricardo Baeza-yates: [link text](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.21.2633)

After building a suffix array ([see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array)), if you are interested in a string with at most k mismatches to the search string, break the search string into k+1 pieces; at least one of those must be intact.  Find the substrings by binary search over the suffix array, then apply the distance function to the patch around each matched piece.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this function

```
CREATE FUNCTION `levenshtein`( s1 text, s2 text) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT; 
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR; 
    DECLARE cv0, cv1 text; 
    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0; 
    IF s1 = s2 THEN 
      RETURN 0; 
    ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN 
      RETURN s2_len; 
    ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN 
      RETURN s1_len; 
    ELSE 
      WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
        SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1; 
      END WHILE; 
      WHILE i <= s1_len DO 
        SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1; 
        WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
          SET c = c + 1; 
          IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN  
            SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1; 
          END IF; 
          SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost; 
          IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF; 
            SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1; 
            IF c > c_temp THEN  
              SET c = c_temp;  
            END IF; 
            SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1; 
        END WHILE; 
        SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1; 
      END WHILE; 
    END IF; 
    RETURN c; 
  END
```

and for getting it as XX% use this function

```
CREATE FUNCTION `levenshtein_ratio`( s1 text, s2 text ) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, max_len INT; 
    SET s1_len = LENGTH(s1), s2_len = LENGTH(s2); 
    IF s1_len > s2_len THEN  
      SET max_len = s1_len;  
    ELSE  
      SET max_len = s2_len;  
    END IF; 
    RETURN ROUND((1 - LEVENSHTEIN(s1, s2) / max_len) * 100); 
  END
```

Comment: Sorry for the noob question but when I copy this to a text file `leven`, and then run `\. leven`, I get multiple errors from MySQL 5: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server... near '' at line 4`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a specialized case of k-distance searching and after installing the Damerau-Levenshtein UDF in MySQL found that the query was taking too long.  I came up with the following solution:

- I have a very restrictive search space (9 character string limited to numeric values).

Create a new table (or append columns to your target table) with columns for each character position in your target field. ie. My VARCHAR(9) ended up as 9 TINYINT columns + 1 Id column that matches my main table (add indexes for each column).  I added triggers to ensure that these new columns always get updated when my main table gets updated.

To perform a k-distance query use the following predicate:

(Column1=s[0]) + (Column2=s[1]) + (Column3=s[2]) + (Column4=s[3]) + ... >= m

where s is your search string and m is the required number of matching characters (or m = 9 - d in my case where d is the maximum distance I want returned).

After testing I found that a query over 1 million rows that was taking 4.6 seconds on average was returning matching ids in less than a second.  A second query to return the data for the matching rows in my main table similarly took under a second.  (Combining these two queries as a subquery or join resulted in significantly longer execution times and I'm not sure why.)

Though this is not Damerau-Levenshtein (doesn't account for substitution) it suffices for my purposes.

Though this solution probably doesn't scale well for a larger (length) search space it worked for this restrictive case very well.