# How to search a 'near word' in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

For example, I want to search a word '**marple**', this should return row with near or exact word like '**marble**','**maple**','**marple**', etc...

How to do it in mysql query? or better give word suggestion if any?

Comment: not an easy problem to solve, AFAIK.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634995/implementation-of-levenshtein-distance-for-mysql-fuzzy-search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SOUNDEX function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex).

*"Two strings that sound almost the same should have identical soundex strings."*

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you can try use soundex function, but it's not a real solution. Use Sphinx or Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

$sql = "select * from tbl_name where your_field like '%your search keyword%'";