# how could I make a search match for similar words

Tags: algorithm, search

I'm working trying to automatically categorize short articles and I'm trying to figure out how to match similar words - eg, shelf shelves or painting and repaint

I'm using the Porter stemming algorithm but it only helps for certain situations and only with the end of the word (both examples above don't work with it).

Is there an algorithm or related word lists that would help with something like this (outside of making my own?)

(I'm working in php so any solutions in that language would be more helpful.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is what you are looking for.

For any two strings, it calculates the minimum number of insertions, mutations and deletions that need to occur to changes one string to the other.

If the distance is low then the two words are similar.

You could also use the [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) algorithm to determine if two words sound similar.

See also:
[PHP levenshtein function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)
[PHP soundex function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php)

Comment: A particular problem with Levenshtein in this kind of context is that you have to find a good threshold; it only returns the number of changes between the two words. There is quite a bit of a difference between the two examples in the original post: levenshtein("shelf", "shelves") = 3, levenshtein("painting", "repaint") = 5.

Comment: for reference - I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634995/implementation-of-levenshtein-distance-for-mysql-fuzzy-search which contains a link to some a mysql stored procedure version.  Though as Jan pointed out, It's not clear yet how close it will come.  But it's worth a try.

Comment: This is the closest answer - it's not ideal but a good start.  The word list from jan is more ideal but not as practical at this point.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is the mother of all "related word lists", called WordNet: http://wordnet.princeton.edu/

It's available free of charge subject to a fairly generous license. There is a PHP interface in the "related projects" section.

The advantage of this over using a word similarity algorithm is that it even knows dissimilar synonyms of words such as "paint" and "colour". The downside is that you either have to know the right synsets (after all, one word can mean different things) or you can get a pretty wild list of synonyms.

Comment: wow - thanks for the link.  I think just understanding the db format would be more time than I have for the project but it seem like the ideal way to go.