# mysql regexp for search using alias

Tags: mysql, regex, search

I am not very good with regexp so I really would like some help to achieve my goal.
When searching in my db I use an alias for specific keywords.

Here is an example

```
keyword  tets alias test   (someone have spell wrong then word test)
keyword  b.m.w  alias bmw  (if someone write b.m.w instead of bmw)
```

etc.

So far if a user searches for `"bmw 316"` I use `LIKE "%bmw%316%"` to get the results. 
Now if the user searches for `"b.m.w 316"` I must use

```
"%b.m.w%316%" OR
"%bmw%316%"
```

because `b.m.w`  has alias `bmw`.

In the case of 6 words with 2-3 aliases there are too many combinations.
I am trying to achieve it with regexp.
In the scenario above it would be something like `(bmw|b.m.w) 316`.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are not looking for `REGEXP` you are looking for a thing [called `levenshtein distance`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

MySQL does not (yet) have native support for this (wonderful) concept, but you can download a UDF here:
http://joshdrew.com/
And here's a list so you've got something to choose from:
http://blog.lolyco.com/sean/2008/08/27/damerau-levenshtein-algorithm-levenshtein-with-transpositions/

You can also write your own function in MySQL, so you don't have to install a UDF.
http://www.supermind.org/blog/927/working-mysql-5-1-levenshtein-stored-procedure

Finally this question might help you out as well:
[Implementation of Levenshtein distance for mysql/fuzzy search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634995/implementation-of-levenshtein-distance-for-mysql-fuzzy-search)

A query for the closest match would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM atable a ORDER BY levenshtein(a.field, '$search') ASC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thank for the links and theory

Comment: You're welcome, it a hard thing to find if you don't know the term to search for. Luckily google fixes any spelling errors otherwise you'd never find it.