# SQL with multiple LIKEs over 1 variable

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM company_address
WHERE address_telephone LIKE '%12%'
AND address_telephone LIKE '%45%' (edit)
```

Short question: Is there a way to only use the column name once?

(edit: It was an example, sorry for that.. )

Comment: it seems like there is no reason to have the LIKE '%12%' at all. Why not only LIKE '%125%'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No

Side note: I do not know your business rules for the query, but it looks like you might want to be using `OR` instead of `AND`.

Long answer: If it was an equality, you could use `IN`. However, since you are using `LIKE`, you have to specify each `LIKE` condition.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do it in one search, you can put your search criteria into a table variable and do a wildcard join on that:

```
DECLARE @t table (s varchar(20))
insert into @t values('12')
insert into @t values('45')

select ca.* from company_address ca inner join
@t t on ca.address_telephone like '%' + t.s + '%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your clause is faulty.  `address_telephone` cannot be `LIKE '%12%'` without also being `LIKE '%125%'` so only the second of them is necessary anyway.

If this is only an example case and you didn't actually intend that `WHERE` logic, [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) might work for your situation:

```
WHERE address_telephone REGEXP '^.*125[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: +1: Shame that `REGEXP` doesn't perform better than wildcarding the left side of a `LIKE` comparison.

Comment: Sorry was making a mistake there... what would you do in this case?

Comment: @Zundrium I would probably use `REGEXP` instead of multiple `LIKE` clauses, if you can compose a regex to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

in your example, yes:

```
SELECT *
FROM company_address
WHERE address_telephone LIKE '%125%'
```

explanation

if `address_telephone LIKE '%125%'` is true
then `address_telephone LIKE '%12%'` must be true as well, so there is no need to add it to the query

Answer (score 0):

You can normally use wildcards etc to combine multiple likes into one statement. See below for a trivial example

```
declare @test varchar(50)    
set @test = '123456789'    
select 'true' where @test like '123%456%9'
```

Edit: That returns 'true', by the way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for a [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) function? It should allow you to do a fuzzy search. There's one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634995/implementation-of-levenshtein-distance-for-mysql-fuzzy-search).