# Sql to return products with matching keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an e-commerce site. I want to upgrade my search functionality.

For Example if I search for sugr it should show the results for 'sugar'
            if I search for gemni it should show the results for 'gemini'

Just the functionality like [Bigbasket](http://bigbasket.com)

My Current functionality works as  [MileStores](http://www.milestores.com)

Comment: most SQL implementations offer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex - so does mssql http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187384.aspx maybe that is already enough for you

Comment: Thnx for your quick response @Najzero will try to work on it

Comment: Also you might want to try edit distance:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634995/implementation-of-levenshtein-distance-for-mysql-fuzzy-search/642215#642215

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [full-text search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). Full-text search uses search-engine technology on the columns you specify when building the full-text index.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SOUNDEX ('SUGAR'),SOUNDEX('sugr')
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx