# About Mysql Fulltext Search

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have a table and some rows, i want do fulltext search but fulltext col without space.

For Example:

My MySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fulltextcol` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fulltextcol` (`fulltextcol`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Inserts:

```
INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `username`, `fulltextcol`) VALUES
(1, 'username1', 'YYYYYNYNYN'),
(2, 'username2', 'NNNNYNYNYN'),
(3, 'username3', 'YYNNYNYYYY'),
(4, 'username4', 'YNYNYNYNYN');
```

And now my mysql command:

```
SELECT *,MATCH(fulltextcol) AGAINST('YNYNYNYNYN') as Relevance 
FROM members
WHERE MATCH(fulltextcol) AGAINST('YNYNYNYNYN' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
HAVING Relevance > 0.2
ORDER BY Relevance DESC
```

Yes everything is OK, bu this query is select only exact match (so select only 4th row) , but i want it must select all of them with scores/relevances.

For example first row have `"YYYYYNYNYN"` and it's not exact match but i want this query select it with low relevance, if 4th row's relevance is 1.18, 1st row's relevance can be 0.32.

I hope I could explain my problem.

How can i do it ?

Comment: Full text searching looks for matching words or prefixes. It doesn't calculate edit distance.

Comment: Yes, i realized it, but i want to learn how can i do this query for results which i want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementation of Levenshtein distance for mysql/fuzzy search?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634995/implementation-of-levenshtein-distance-for-mysql-fuzzy-search)

Comment: Thanks, i found a way for my problem. It's link of solution of my problem, if anybody have same problem with me, this link help him.

http://dannykopping.com/blog/fuzzy-text-search-mysql-jaro-winkler