# How to use the LIKE operator with partial word matching?

Tags: mysql

How can I have `I want to eat rice` match `I wan to eat ric`? The issue is the `wan` portion.

DB:

```
dialogue          | category
                  |
Want to eat rice  | food
```

SQL:

```
SELECT category FROM `categories` WHERE dialogue LIKE '%I wan to eat ric%'
```

This returns no results. It should return `food`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634995/implementation-of-levenshtein-distance-for-mysql-fuzzy-search

Comment: @jarlh I'm using MYSQL